Django sync_to_async blocking event_loop on ORM queries?
So I am using asyncio and Django and to use Django's ORM you need to either use asnyc methods or wrap the ORM calls in sync_to_async. I am having some questions however understanding if while I am waiting for the response from the database the event loop is freed to do other operations ex:
def sync_function(user_id, name):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    last_name_user = User.objects.filter(name=name).last()
    return user, last_name_user

If I do
async def async_function(user_id, name):
   user, last_name_user = await sync_to_async(sync_function)(user_id, name)

will my event loop be free to do other CPU bound operations while those querys are done?
I am also aware there are aget and alast methods but it seems all they do is wrap the actual method with sync_to_async so I'd also like to know if there would be a difference between the example I provided earlier and
async def async_function(user_id, name):
   user = await User.objects.aget(id=user_id)
   last_name_user = await User.objects.filter(name=name).alast()

I read a bit about thread_sensitive parameter in sync_to_async is my understanding that by default being True it means that function wrapped will be ran in the same thread and thus the event loop wont be able to run other tasks, and if it is False it could be parallelized?
